# jQuery each singular alternative

Tags: jquery

I often see jQuery code similar to some form of `.each()` where it has an ID selector:

```
$('#selector').each(function(index, element){
    // do something
});
```

Now, understanding that there will only be one element with that ID but I want to maintain the chain-ability of the jQuery object is there some other option other than the `.each()`.  **Is there some way without the overhead of the `.each()` here?**

(I know it nitpicks as the overhead of the interal `for` of the each is not huge)

Something like this example fake "justme":

```
$('#selector').justme(function(myElement){
    alert(myElement.id);
    // do something
}).parent('div')...
```

I know there are for example:

```
$('#selector').eq(0)
$('#selector')[0]
```

But these lack the function or break the jQuery chain.

Comment: `eq()` doesn't break the chain and since there is only one selected element you don't need it.

Comment: only the methods that do not return `this` will break the chain and `eq(` is not one of them

Comment: @undefined - true, but it lacks the `.eq(0,function(){})` form

Comment: why do u need to use `.each()` for only one element? just because u see it elsewhere doesn't mean its right, 99% of the time `.each()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea - exactly, other than a plugin there seems no built-in alternative to `.each()` if you have a known singular such as an ID selector.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Right, but why exactly do you need the each? i see nothing in the code you presented that requires an each.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - no i mean what FUNCTION would u need it for? what are u applying to it that requires the use of `.each()` at all? that was my point, u likely dont.

Comment: According to jsperf my browser is able to run 186,357 operations a second. The test was to select one single element and, using `.each()`, set the html (using .innerHTML to increase speed). I know it doesn't make sense (each of one...) but it really doesn't affect application performance.

Comment: @Joe: thank you for the sanity. Also, the very slight (sub-1%) performance loss is offset by the gain of chainability, which you cannot get other than by wrapping your unique element in an IETF - which is a performance loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the extra overhead (or lack thereof), but if you really wanted such a plugin, it's easy to write.

```
$.fn.justme = function(callback){
    callback.apply(this[0]);
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question rather than simply admonishing a somewhat theoretical question given as I had previously stated in my that I was quite aware of the fact that the overhead was minuscule for the `.each()`.

Answer (score 4):

I honestly have no idea what you are talking about on "each overhead". `each` is implemented as follows:

```
each: function(fct) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
       fct.apply(this.elements[i]);
    }
    return this;
}
```

There IS no overhead! It leverages a native property of JS, which is closure re-scoping. For one element, you are losing on performance in one assignment, one arithmetic comparison and one increment, all three of which are atomic operations. That's a negligible overhead.

Comment: I refer to the `for` function as overhead in this limited context, however small, it exists

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: by that reasoning, why don't you throw all of jQuery out? It is overhead, no matter how small, as you could do all it does better in native code. You'll be gaining less than 8 clock cycles by performing this "optimization", and this, only when the jQuery wrapper contains one and only one element.

Comment: I mean you COULD reduce the overhead by changing it to `for(var i = this.elements.length; i--;)` if you werent worried about order, but the overhead of changing that function would be more than that gained unless used EVERYWHERE.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea: Micro-optimized gain of 0.88% per run. Not bad. :P

Comment: If you only have ONE you don't need a `for` loop at all.

Comment: haha yeah i mean it was a separate point, kind of as a joke. and @MarkSchultheiss thats an excellent point, almost like it invalidates the entire question. :P

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: you do realize that a `for` structure is virtually costless, right? Here is a benchmark for you to believe it: http://jsperf.com/inc-vs-dec-test-stack . You've just gained 0.6%, which you have lost already by loading jQuery (and then more). Congrats.

Comment: (The real question is: if you are sure that you only have one element...why are you even using each?)